# bash storing a variable and silence the result

Tags: bash, shell

I want to do something like this in bash:

```
NUMBER_OF_WHATEVER="$(command | command2 | command3 )" 2>&1 /dev/null
```

So I want to store the output on the variable but also not print it. This clearly doesnt stop the stderr from printing (I can see error msgs from command1 coming out).

Thanks

Comment: Your redirection looks a bit weird to me - shouldn't it be `2>/dev/null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` in each command of your pipeline or use `list {...} 2>/dev/null`:

```
{ number_of_whatever="$(command | command2 | command3)"; } 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Or you can factor the redirections as `{ var=$( ... ); } 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: the problem with this is that the value 2>&1 /dev/null is being stored on the variable

Comment: @user3124171: Why do you have `2>&1` I don't have that in my answer. Also try my updated answer based on @gniourf_gniourf 's good suggestion

Comment: You can also "globally" redirect standard error inside the command substitution. `num=$(exec 2> /dev/null; command | command2 | command3)`

Answer (score 0):

You must write it like this:

```
NUMBER_OF_WHATEVER=$(command 2> /dev/null | command2 2> /dev/null | command3 2> /dev/null)
```

Comment: the problem with this is that the value 2>&1 /dev/null is being stored on the variable.. similar problem with the above. So basically the variable = NULL

Comment: well im writing a parser.. so there are several commands used.. But the solution works like a charm!